# Disable contact birthday events with Einstein Activity Capture

Tags: contact, event, einstein, birthday

is there a way to disable contact's birthday event with Einstein Activity Capture?

Every day, I get a lot of event notifications in Outlook because of contact's birthdays.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the outlook is creating calendar birthday events automatically when new contact records are created in Outlook and because you set up Einstein Activity Capture, those events are syncing to Salesforce.

This is basic functionality of Outlook that if you create a new contact record and you fill out the birthday field, it will automatically create a calendar event for the birthday of that newly added contact. And because you’re using Einstein if your sync direction is "Office 365 to Salesforce", all events created from Outlook will definitely sync to your Salesforce calendar.

To prevent this from happening, the best thing to do is to set your event sync direction to “Salesforce to Office 365” so that whenever a birthday event will be automatically created in Outlook, it won’t sync to Salesforce.

Other options:

Events Sync [How Private Events Sync with Einstein Activity Capture](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=aac_event_sync_private_events.htm&type=5)

- If the Birthday Event was from the Calendar of the user they can mark these as 'Private' in order for it to be excluded on the Event sync.

[Birthday Reminders in Outlook](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37810.outlook-troubleshooting-how-to-remove-birthday-calendars-from-view.aspx)

- The advanced sync settings for the Einstein Activity Capture can only add filters to stop the syncing of Contacts through the Birthday Field. If needing to stop the Birthday reminders I believe the best way to do this is to turn off this setting in Outlook.

Turn off automatic birthday reminders
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_other-mso_2007/turn-off-automatic-birthday-reminders/82650cff-cc39-464c-beeb-145f4e27ba86